# Как правильно сделать связку в Docker: php + cron?

Tags: linux, docker

В Docker нужно сделать так, чтобы в cron раз в сутки запускался php скрипт. Скажите, как правильно это реализовать? В интернете встречал вариант запустить в одном контейнере через supervisor сразу 2 процесса (fpm и cron), но другие говорят что каждый процесс должен быть изолирован. Так же встречал другой вариант, когда в хост-системе прописывается в крон что-то в духе docker exec php /path/to/php/script.php, но это сильно смахивает на костыль. Я создал 2 контейнера: в одном php в другом cron. Связал их с помощью links и volumes, но я не могу вызвать из крона php скрипт из другого контейнера. Скажите, как все таки правильно это сделать?

Файл docker-compose.yml

```
cron:
    build: ./
    links:
        - "php"
    volumes:
        - "./:/home"

php:
    image: php
    command: tail -f /dev/null
    volumes:
        - "./:/home"
```

Файл Dockerfile

```
FROM centos
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install crontabs
RUN sed -i -e '/pam_loginuid.so/s/^/#/' /etc/pam.d/crond
ADD cron /etc/cron.d/cron_test
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/cron_test
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/cron_test
CMD crond && tail -f /dev/null
```

Comment: концептуально правильно (именно для docker-а) будет запуск контейнера (читай — процесса) **только** в нужный вам момент времени, а не засорение машины двумя **постоянно** работающими контейнерами (читай — процессами).

Comment: *Так же встречал другой вариант, когда в хост-системе прописывается в крон что-то в духе docker exec php /path/to/php/script.php, но это сильно смахивает на костыль* — вот это как раз и есть «**не** костыль». правильно и концептуально и для избежания бездумного расходования ресурсов.

Comment: судя по всему, вы (пока) не поняли смысл docker-а. это средство для запуска одного процесса в изолированном окружении. запустили процесс (т.е. контейнер), он выполнил свою задачу, и завершил работу. вот для этого docker и служит. ну, по крайней мере, в первую очередь.

Comment: Для меня докер это прежде всего быстрое и удобное разворачивание рабочего окружения. Можно быстро и безболезнено вносить изменения в конфигурацию сервера. По сравнению с вагрантом земля и небо. А в чем профит изолирования процесса я не понимаю. Какая разница где процесс проживет свое время на реальной ОС или в докере.

Comment: *1. Можно быстро и **безболезнено** вносить изменения в конфигурацию сервера 2. А в чем профит изолирования процесса я не понимаю* — сначала сами ответили, потом сами же и спросили (выделение — моё).